# Create a file on the desktop. (C++)

Tags: c++, windows

I Created a little program for write the same text infinity times with a little delay, but I don't know how to access to desktop directory without the name of the user. Thank you for help me!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std; 
int main(){
bool infinity = true;
string Testo = "Come fossero i giocatori senza denti?";
ofstream File ("C:\\Users\\(name of user)\\Open Me.txt");
while(infinity){
    File << Testo << endl;
    Sleep(1000);
}
}
```

Comment: Check `%HOMEPATH%` [environment variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getenvironmentvariable).

Comment: I added the windows tag because doing this on Android, linux or macOS or some other OS could be different.

Comment: @Evg I tried to write %HOMEPATH% before "\\desktop" and after "\\Users\\ but didn't works );

Comment: "didn't works" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/

Comment: I want to create a file in the desktop directory but I don't know the name of the user of the person who use it, I need how to get the desktop directory without the name of user, I tried to use "%HOMEPATH% in the user name space but I can't create the file, there aren't errors, the program starts.

Comment: You could also use this to get the path: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetknownfolderpath?redirectedfrom=MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetknownfolderpath?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: I don't know how to use it, I'm beginner in C++ ):

Comment: Google for some examples.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, you should consider using `getenv()` function, something like (notice comments):

```
// Function to return the value of Environment Variable
std::string getEnv(const std::string& param) {
    char *val = getenv(key.c_str());
    // If the environment key isn't available, then return an empty string
    return (val == NULL) ? std::string("") : std::string(val);
}

int main(void) {
    // Dynamic location to use with the help of env. key
    std::string location = "C:\\" + getEnv("HOMEPATH") + "\\File.txt";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I Think i'm so beginner in c++, I need to improve my ability because he didn't work. Thank you for help me, bye :D